# Render image from Contentful to Netlify

Tags: json, angular, blogs, netlify, contentful

I have a problem displaying the images I upload to contentful on my angular site. From the browser console the image is correctly loaded but I see a blank image on the screen.
The problem is cmplazyload class but I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Below my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-3 justify-content-center attraction-post-container" *ngIf="venditaPosts$ | async as venditaPosts">
      <div class="col" *ngFor="let venditaPost of venditaPosts.items">
        <div class="container-fluid text-start">
            <img [src]="venditaPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url" class="img-fluid" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            <h2 class="fs-4 py-1">{{venditaPost.fields.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{venditaPost.fields.summary}}</p>
            <a [routerLink]="['/venditaPost', venditaPost.sys.id]" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Leggi di più</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the code from browser console:

```
<img _ngcontent-ng-c3011936239="" loading="lazy" class="img-fluid cmplazyload" style="width: 80%;" data-cmp-src="//images.ctfassets.net/i5j1ijnpcg10/6HXAA31mcFRXEn53URNArv/a23c09547f113536c6d5d02704caa164/IMG_20230703_095627937.jpg" src="" data-cmp-fnab="1" data-cmp-info="12">
```

In my local environment I see the images. Online I can't see the images because this

```
data-cmp-src
```